# Picking up all properties except specified ones

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface Buba {
    k1: string;
    k2: string;
    k3: number;
}
```

I would like to create a new type based on this definition with all its properties except specified ones. For instance I want to get rid of k1. Is something like this even possible?

```
type PickedBuba = Pick<Buba, !'k1'> // { k2: string, k3: number }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems I have found a way how to do it. We will need a helper type **StringOmit**

```
type StringOmit<L1 extends string, L2 extends string> = ({ [P in L1]: P } &
    { [P in L2]: never } & { [key: string]: never })[L1];
```

Then we can write our own implementation of PickOmit

```
type PickOmit<O, K extends string> = Pick<O, StringOmit<keyof O, K>>;
```

Then the solution would look sth like this:

```
type PickedBuba = PickOmit<Buba, 'k1'> // { k2: string, k3: number }
```

**EDIT**
With Typescript 2.8 we can implement Omit taking advantage of conditional types and new built-in type **Exclude**:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

**EDIT2**
With TypeScript 3.5 we finally have a built-in Omit type.

Comment: tnks for this; I'm using `type PickOmit<O, K extends keyof O> = Pick<O, StringOmit<keyof O, K>>;` to be protected in case I accidentally use a string that is not a key of O, or more importantly if I change O's definition in the future (typescript 2.7.1)

Comment: **UPDATE:** TypeScript now has the `Omit` type as part of its standard library, which means you won't have to declare it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the new [`Omit` Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)

```
interface Buba {
    k1: string;
    k2: string;
    k3: number;
}

type PickedBuba = Omit<Buba, 'k1'> // { k2: string, k3: number }
```